# How to send invite to multiple user/whole origination at once in GITHUB repository not one by one

Tags: github

I have build a repository of codes named XYZ on github. I want to share my repository with the entire organization (more the 250 members). For that, I have to add all the members one by one which makes the task tedious.

Is there any simpler way to share this repository with only read access to multiple users at once?
Note: This git account is at the organizational level it's not personal account so it should be limited up to our organization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wish to give read permissions to everyone in your GitHub organization, you can do this by setting "Base Permissions" under "Member Privileges" in the organization account settings to "Read".

Reference: [Setting base permissions for an organization](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/setting-base-permissions-for-an-organization#setting-base-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

It's function to invite the user to repo. you can change the permission
levels.

```py
from github import Github
import json

token = ""
g = Github(token)
```

```py
def get_org(org_name="org_name"):
    """ Get organization

    Args:
        org_name: Name of organization

    Returns:
        org: Organization object

    """
    return g.get_organization(org_name)
```

```py
class InviteUser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.org = None

   def invite_user_to_repo(self, user_name, repo_name="Getting-Started"):
        """ Invite user to repository

        Args:
            user_name: Name of user
            repo_name: Name of repository

        Returns:
            None

        """
        if self.org is None:
            self.org = get_org()
        repo = self.org.get_repo(repo_name)
        user = g.get_user(user_name)
        repo.add_to_collaborators(user, permission="push")
```

## requirements:- pygithub